# How to move an Android App in Auto Start List of Mi Note3, so it receives Push even app is closed

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, autostart

I am working on an android app and from last 2 weeks i am facing a issue in MI Phones that they don't receive Push Notification when application is in Background State or Inactive State. This is working great in other devices like samsung, micromax etc.

At last i solve it by Moving My application in Auto Start Mode through Device Permission Section

Security -> Permission Section -> Auto Start -> MY_APP -> Mark Toggle to On.

When i follow above steps i found that Facebook and whatsapp are already in AutoStart List, means it is possible to move an android application in AutoStart by code.

So can anybody please help me with some piece of code or Tutorials which i can follow to solve this issue.

Comment: These apps are probably synced from their server or hardcoded in app. I couldn't find anything in de-compiled apk. So I guess the easiest way is redirect user to that app for auto start setting.

Comment: I am also interested in finding the answer. I suspect Mi maintains a white list internally.

Comment: i suspect its just MI issue. I guess it has to with with android version, marshmallow may not be allowing this. But its just a guess as you had to manage permissions in settings which comes only in Marshmallow. Not too sure about Mi device ROMs

Comment: The Same thing is existing in EMUI (Huawei).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cordova-plugin-autostart](https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart) by enabling autostart after boot

```
cordova.plugins.autoStart.enable();
```

If enabled is not called, then by default it will be disabled

```
cordova.plugins.autoStart.disable();
```

In the config.xml the following needs to be added

```
<gap:plugin platform="android" name="cordova-plugin-autostart" version="2.0.1" source="npm"/>
```

**NOTE:** Installation to the SD card will prevent the automatic start of your app after the boot

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with mi 3 but bro its not possible from lollipop and marshmallow cause of security reason. But if your phone is rooted then you can change it to allow.